# Upload images array to firebase storage and return its urls React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I'm uploading images to firebase storage and I don't have problems with that, but the reference that I have, return the names of the images in an array called imagesBlob. I want to return the download URL of every image after upload and put it into that imagesBlob array.

How can I do that??

Here is my function:

```
    const uploadImagesStorage = async (imageArray) => {
        const imagesBlob = [];

        await Promise.all(
            imageArray.map(async (image) => {
                const response = await fetch(image);
                const blob = await response.blob();
                const ref = firebase
                    .storage()
                    .ref('provider-images')
                    .child(uuidv4());
                await ref.put(blob).then((result) => {
                    imagesBlob.push(result.metadata.name);
                });
            }),
        );

        getImageUrls(imagesBlob);
    };
```

Comment: just after the file get uploaded call the function ref.getDownloadUrl [check for typos] and get the url then resolve the promise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added 
`await ref.getDowloadURL().then((result) => { imagesBlob.push(result })` but now I want to know if there is a way to keep the original order of the array because I'm using the first image in the array as the profile picture of the provider. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: why are you keeping stale data. just delte the old one and dont put dp in an array just keep a single field and delete the old dp from storage. users wont like it if they get to know that you are keeping their data

Comment: Thanks for the observation, probably I need to explain it with more details. I'm starting a project where users can create a profile for a store for sales through the app. Also, they will have to add products. When they were creating their profiles, they can upload up to three images and I take the first as their profile image. I will change that so they have just one that could be replaced as you mention, but I'm thinking of using the same logic when they create products so they could upload up to 3 images per product and the first one will be the product's primary image.

Comment: well i appreiciate it you are trying to create a universal data model for you use case. now i can give you a hint => you can easily find out what has changed in an array using a loop. so place a trigger on profile data change and check what has changed and do things accordinly